# Front Page menu is hidden somewhere

Tags: html, css

Good Morning form Tokyo.
I am making an eccommerce site with ECCUBE Version 3.0 . It gives us template of their own but I have tweaked it using some css and html.

However my problem is that when I switch my site to mobile view and open the menu bar which is top right corner, It shows nothing. Menu tab is opened but there is nothing inside it. But If I move to other pages like products page, or FAQ page from same mobile view and open the menu, it displays the content of the menu. 
I know menu is there but I dont know its hidden or being overlapped.
This is my site [AZlily](http://azlily.awe.jp/eccube_1/). 
And here are code for top page with css.

```css
/* This is Default.css of main page css */
@charset "utf-8";

/* --------------------------------
 Theme CSS for EC-CUBE 3
-------------------------------- */


/* --------------------------------
 Common
-------------------------------- */

body {
 font-family: Roboto, "游ゴシック", YuGothic, "Yu Gothic", "ヒラギノ角ゴ ProN W3", "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN", Arial, "メイリオ", Meiryo, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.4;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 color: #525263;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

.img_center,
.txt_center {
 text-align: center;
}
.img_right,
.txt_right {
 text-align: right;
}

/****** Base Layout Setting ********/

#header {
 background: #fff;
}
#contents {
 background: #fff;
}

/****** Header Setting ********/


.header_logo_area {
 margin-right: 100px;
}
.header_logo_area .header_logo a:link,
.header_logo_area .header_logo a:visited,
.header_logo_area .header_logo a:hover,
.header_logo_area .header_logo a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
}
.header_logo_area .header_logo a:hover {
 color: #666;
}


/****** Side Setting ********/

/****** Footer Setting ********/

/****** Effect Setting ********/


/****** Each BlockParts Setting ********/

/* cart area */

#cart_area {
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0; top: 0;
 z-index: 11;
}
#cart_area p {
 margin: 0;
}
#cart_area p.cart-trigger {
 position: absolute;
 right: 65px;
}

#cart .inner {
 background: #f3f3f3;
}


/* search area */

#search {
 background: #EBEBEB;
 padding: 16px 8px;
}
#search select {
 width: 100%;
}

/* snsbtn_area */
.snsbtn_area .snsbtn {
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

/* --------------------------------
 Top Page
-------------------------------- */

.front_page a:hover img {
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.front_page #contents .row > div {
 padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.front_page #contents .row.no-padding > div {
 padding-bottom: 0;
}

/* Comment Area */

.front_page .comment_area h4 {
 font-size: 24px;
 font-size: 2.4rem;
 margin: 0 0 2px;
}
.front_page .comment_area h5 {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-size: 1.6rem;
 margin: 0;
}
.front_page .comment_area p {
 margin: 10px 0 15px;
}

/* Item List */

.front_page .item_comment {
 color: #444;
}
.front_page .item a {
 padding-bottom: 0;
}
.front_page .item a:hover {
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.front_page .item a:hover img {
 opacity: 1;
}
.front_page #contents_top .item_comment {
 color: #525263;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-size: 1.4rem;
}
.front_page #contents_top .item_comment.text-warning,
.front_page #contents_top .item_name.text-warning {
 color: #9a947e;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.front_page .more_link.text-warning {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #9A947E;
}

/* news_area */

.news_contents {
 padding: 0;
}
#news_area {
 background: #F8F8F8;
}
#news_area .heading01 {
 padding: 8px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
}

/* txt_bnr */

.txt_bnr_area {
 padding: 0 0 16px;
}

.txt_bnr {
 /*background: #f8f8f8;
 border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;*/
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 16px;
 margin: 12px 0 0;
 text-align: center;
}
.txt_bnr strong {
 color: #DE5D50;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-size: 2rem;
}
.txt_bnr strong strong {
 font-size: 32px;
 font-size: 3.2rem;
}

.item_gallery {
 clear: both;
}

/* --------------------------------
 Detail Page
-------------------------------- */

#item_detail + row {
 margin-top: -1px;
 background: #fff;
}

/*#item_detail .btn_area li:last-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}
*/


/* Slider */
.slick-loading .slick-list {
    background: #fff url('ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat;
}


/* Arrow */

.slick_prev,
.slick_next {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 width: 40px; height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
}

/* Dots */
.slick-slider {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slick-dots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.slick-dots li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;

    cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-dots li button {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover,
.slick-dots li button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover:before,
.slick-dots li button:focus:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-dots li button:before {
 content:" ";
    line-height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: .25;
    background-color: black;
 border-radius: 50%;

}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
    opacity: .75;
    background-color: black;
}

.slick-dots li button.thumbnail img {
 width: 0; height: 0;
}

#item_photo_area .slick-slide {
 text-align: center;
}
#item_photo_area .slick-slide img {
 display: inline-block;
}


/******************************
 Media Query
*******************************/

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

 /* --------- common ---------- */


 /****** Header Setting ********/


 /****** Side Setting ********/


 /****** Effect Setting ********/


}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

 /* --------- common ---------- */

 #contents {
  padding-top: 30px;
 }

 /****** Header Setting ********/

 /****** Layout ********/

 /* header */

 #header .header_logo_area {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 265px;
 }
 #header #drawer #search {
  position: relative;
 }
 #search {
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #member {
  float: right;
 }

 .member ul li {
  display: inline-block;
 }



 /****** Side Setting ********/

 /****** Footer Setting ********/

 /****** Each BlockParts Setting ********/

 /* search area */

 #search select {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 180px;
 }
 /* cart */

 #cart .inner {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; top: 0;
 }
 #cart_area {
  top: 0; right: 16px;
 }
 #cart_area p {
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  float: right;
  min-width: 256px;
 }
 #cart_area p.cart-trigger {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
 }
 #cart_area .inner {
  min-width: 256px;
 }
 #cart_area .cart_price {
  font-size: 12px;
 }
 #cart_area .cart_price .price {
  font-size: 16px;
 }


 /* --------------------------------
  Top Page
 -------------------------------- */

 .front_page #contents .row {
  padding-bottom: 24px;
 }
 /* Comment Area */

 .front_page .comment_area h4 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
 }
 .front_page .comment_area h5 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 2rem;
 }
 .front_page .comment_area p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 24px 0 24px;
 }

 /* news_area */

 .news_contents {
  padding: 0 16px 0 0;
 }

 #news_area .heading01 {
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: left;
 }
 #news_area {
  margin-bottom: 32px;
 }


 /* txt_bnr */

 .txt_bnr_area {
  padding-left: 16px;
 }

 .txt_bnr {
  margin:0 0 16px;
 }

 /* --------------------------------
  Detail Page
 -------------------------------- */

 #item_photo_area .slick-dots {
  margin: 0 -16px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
 }
 #item_photo_area .slick-dots::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
 }

 #item_photo_area .slick-dots li {
  width: 33.33333333%; height: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
 }

 .slick-dots li button.thumbnail {
  width: 100%; height: auto;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .slick-dots li button.thumbnail img {
  width: 100%; height: auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
 }
 .slick-dots li button.thumbnail:hover img,
 .slick-dots li.slick-active button.thumbnail img {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 .slick-dots li button.thumbnail::before {
  display: none;
 }
}

/* --------------------------------
    display mask
-------------------------------- */
.prevention-masked {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3040;
    background-color: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .5;
}

.extra-form {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
//This is top page html//

{% extends 'default_frame.twig' %}

{% set body_class = 'front_page' %}

{% block javascript %}
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.main_visual').slick({
        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        autoplay: true,
        speed: 300
    });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="main_visual">
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://azlily.awe.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/main-gra_pc.jpg" height="475">
                </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}



//This is menu block html //
{% macro tree(Category) %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url('product_list') }}?category_id={{ Category.id }}">
            {{ Category.name }}
        </a>
        {% if Category.children|length > 0 %}
            <ul>
            {% for ChildCategory in Category.children %}
                    {{ _self.tree(ChildCategory) }}
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endmacro %}

 

<nav id = "category" class = "drawer_block pc"> 
<ul class = "category-nav">


<li class="topmenu1"><a href="#">トップページ</a></li>
<li class="topmenu2"><a href="#"> 製品紹介</a></li>
<li class="topmenu3"><a href="#">AZLilyについて</a></li>
<li class="topmenu4"><a href="#">How to Use</a></li>
<li class="topmenu5"><a href="#">Column</a></li>
<li class="topmenu6"><a href="#">LOVE統計</a></li>
<li class="topmenu7"><a href="#">メディア紹介</a></li>
<li class="topmenu8"><a href="#">よくある質問</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

If menu were to collasped it would have not seen in other pages too. But i think its issue with top page .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi Fpl Nepal**
I saw your website and I have found your mistake due to which you are facing a problem.

**Showing Menu**

you can see that your Div who has `Drawer` class is the sibling of `contents` class.
[image: image that show menu]

**Hidden Menu**

you can see that your Div who has `Drawer` class is the child of `contents` class.
[image: image of hide menu]

> `So go to your HTML file and make sibling the div of **Drawer**` class and the div of **contents** class

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? make sibling the div of **Drawer** ? I am still confused

Comment: U can now see the images I hope you can understand the difference.

Comment: No I didnt write any codes there, + I dont know where that html file lies. I had just tweaked with CSS and thats all. This is top page, and when i see inside top page block, above html or codes are only there. Its the pre template file. I cant edit it coz i havent edit it before too.

Comment: but the problem is in the HTML file. if you can send me your HTML file then i can solve your problem

Comment: Is there anyway to send you files? I cant find the html files. Its not directly . I can give you access to my database and ftp

Comment: Also. If i swtiched to other page, HTML is fine, like its div is not a child. Means something is changing the parameter there. Coz I havent touch the html file, coz i dont have access to it.

Comment: yes you can send me ur ftp access here at my  gamil account mtahseen1122@gmail.com

Comment: yes html is according to style in other pages but in main page HTML is not fine

Comment: Its kay. I solved it. By editing top page template directly from root

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Fpl Nepal**
This is the html source of "about" page:

[image]

"drawer" div is sibling of "contents" div. But in main page it is inside of contenst:

[image]

Looks like you have changed some of html elements and maybe missed a closing tag somewhere.

Comment: Yes, thats the proble, But I didnt write any code or edited . Coz I dont have access to that files., I just  tweaked some css and thats all. I even dont know where the html file sit. Coz this eccube worls with termplates and block only.